# Assist with batch file that searches and xcopy hidden file to specific dir

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

It's annoying to manually always search in the **CMD** and **xcopy** the hidden file, can someone whos good in scipting help me out?

I use these 2 commands:
Firstly i open CMD in the **FOLDER2** and entering this command to find the hidden file in the hidden random sub dir:
`dir /s /b | find "robotknow"`

> (**robotknow** is not the fullname of the file, only part of it.)

And then when it find the hidden file within the random made subdir i copy the whole path including the whole filename with the ending.

`Xcopy /h *The whole path including the filename and ending* C:\hello`

**My folders:**

```
$sourceDir = 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\FOLDER1\FOLDER2'

$targetDir = 'C:\hello'
```

So i wish to create a batch that could search that string "robotknow" and copy the fullname of the file to my tagetdir.

Is it possible?
Im trying to learn commands but batching is harder, if i was unclear on anything please ask me thank you!

**Edit:**
I found few commands that could be useful but I dont know how to use them so that it works.

`$searchStrings =`  For it to search after the string above i mentioned: **"robotknow"**
**And**
`Copy-Item $_.FullName $targetpath`

**An example would be:**

The filename has this in it's name **"robotknow"** and i want to copy it.
Copy the file im searching after to copy thats within the sub folder of the **FOLDER2** which is an hidden random folder that i cannot se:
`%LocalAppData%\Packages\FOLDER1\FOLDER2\THE-hidden-RANDOM-made-sub-DIR`.

Copy it to it's final directory `c:\hello`
The final directory, simply just: `c:\hello`.

By hidden i mean that i cannot see in file explorer, windows GUI and neither if i put this simple command in CMD `dir` to show the hidden random folder where the file is located in, they are not showing.

The file only appears in CMD if i enter this command `dir /s /b | find "robotknow"` when im in the **FOLDER2**.
Only after that i can se the hidden random made dir/folder and the full hidden path to it (the file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest following batch file code for this task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "SourceFolder=%LocalAppData%\Packages\FOLDER1\FOLDER2"
set "TargetFolder=C:\hello"
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%SourceFolder%\*robotknow*" /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do %SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%%~dpI*" "%TargetFolder%\" /C /E /H /K /Q /R /Y >nul
endlocal
```

The command **FOR** with option `/F` starts a separate command process with `cmd.exe /C` (more precisely `%ComSpec% /C`) in background to run the command line:

```
dir "C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Packages\FOLDER1\FOLDER2\*robotknow*" /A-D /B /S 2>nul
```

**DIR** outputs to handle **STDOUT** of background command process

- just the names of all **files** matching the wildcard pattern `*robotknow*` because of option `/A-D` (attribute not directory)
- even on file having hidden attribute set because of using option `/A` and not excluding attribute hidden
- in bare format because of option `/B`
- with full qualified path because of option `/S`
- found in specified directory or any subdirectory also because of option `/S`.

It is possible that **DIR** does not find any file system entry matching these criteria in which case it outputs an error message to handle **STDERR**. This error message is suppressed by redirecting it to device **NUL**.

Read the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

**FOR** with option `/F` captures all lines output to handle **STDOUT** of started command process and processes them line by line after started `cmd.exe` terminated itself.

**FOR** ignores empty lines which do not occur here. **FOR** ignores by default also all lines starting with a semicolon because of `eol=;` is the default for end of line character option. But a full qualified file name consisting of full file path, file name and file extension cannot start with `;` and so default end of line option can be kept in this case. **FOR** splits up the lines by default into substrings with using normal space and horizontal tab character as string delimiters and assigns just first space/tab separated substring to specified loop variable. This line splitting behavior is not wanted here because of file path could contain a space character. For that reason option `delims=` is used to define an empty list of delimiters which disables the line splitting behavior.

So **FOR** assigns to specified and case-sensitive interpreted loop variable `I` the full qualified file name found and output by **DIR** and runs the command **XCOPY**.

**XCOPY** is executed with source being the full qualified path of found file referenced with `%%~dpI` always ending with a backslash concatenated with wildcard `*` and destination directory being specified target folder `C:\hello`.

The appended backslash at end of destination directory path makes it 100% clear for **XCOPY** that the destination is a directory and not a file which prevents the prompt if destination means a directory or a file. `\` at end makes also usage of option `/I` unnecessary and **XCOPY** creates the entire destination directory structure if necessary.

The other **XCOPY** options are for really copying all files including files with hidden attribute set in directory containing the file matching the wildcard pattern `*robotknow*` with all subdirectories including empty subdirectories to destination directory with keeping attributes including read-only attribute.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `xcopy /?`

See also the list of predefined [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows).